# I want to update the BIOS on ASUS X540LJ Laptop, but I find two different model numbers

Tags: bios

I have BIOS version 203, and version 305 is the newest. I want to update, but I see two different model numbers. Here's the output of the BIOS part in `dmidecode`:

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: X540LJ.203
    Release Date: 10/13/2015
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 6464 kB
```

There is says ASUS X540LJ. However, on the back of the computer it says X540L. I don't know what version to get. The reason I want to update is that the new BIOS has "Optimized system performance".

Comment: You should ask ASUS support. Installing the wrong update could brick your computer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I know it could be bricked. I will ask the ASUS Support, thank you

Comment: X540LJ exists as a product on their website, X540L does not...if you run msinfo32.exe what is shown as the 'System Model' in the System Summary section?

Comment: I don't run Windows...But `inxi -Fxz` gives me  `model: X540LJ`. I think It's the right one